# how to clear blank lines before the start of feed content for wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, rss, feed, w3c-validation

Our site has a category feed URL and it is giving an an error if tried to generate a `SimpleXMLElement`.

```
http://www.e4s.co.uk/blogs/employers/category/articles/feed/
```

I validated the URL at http://validator.w3.org/appc/ and it is showing that blank lines at the beginning is the issue.

How can I remove the blank lines. I mean in which file do i need to change ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the white space, look at your theme's `header.php` and remove any white space you see at the top of the file. It should ideally only contain `<?php` on the first line of the document and no white space between the closing `?>` and your DOCTYPE declaration, e.g.

```
<?php
/**
 * header.php
 */
?><!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- rest of file... -->
```

Looking at a [content page](http://www.e4s.co.uk/blogs/employers/) on your site, I see there's no closing `</body>` or `</html>` which leads me to believe that your template is missing a `get_footer();` call or `footer.php` is incomplete.

Comment: @NaanuManu -- Let's chat about this further: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18998/room-for-stealthyninja-and-naanumanu

Comment: As @stealthyninja said, it's not just the header than can mess this up, I had a `content-single.php` file in a child theme, with a gap *after* the initial PHP tag but before the opening `<article>`, which broke all RSS feeds (symptom: Firefox thought they were a "Safari document" and would refuse to open them itself.)

Comment: Also: omit closing PHP tags from files like `functions.php` to avoid introducing a blank line at the *end* of a file which will end up at the *start* of your theme…